# How to implement two radios in Veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I want to implement an protocol with two radios switched on different frequencies. Can I just add an additional *PhyLayer80211p* module in the *Nic80211p* module?

If so, how do I address them? If I see it correctly, the `findModule` method used in *Mac1609_4.cc:37* has no attribute to specify which Phy-module he should return. That way i can't specify which of the two radios should be set to `RadioState TX` (as well as which frequency it is set to).

Would it differ automatically between the two channels if i just send a message two the right gate to the phyModule and set them on seperate frequencies before? e.g.

```
sendDelayed(mac, RADIODELAY_11P, lowerLayerOut); vs. sendDelayed(mac, RADIODELAY_11P, lowerControlLayerOut);
```

Any other tips? Thanks!